# How to get on wifi without administrator password

Tags: wireless, password

How can I get online on a Ubuntu PC without the administrator password? I have ordinary user privileges, and the wifi itself is not password protected.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244567/remove-sudo-password-when-connecting-to-new-wifi-network

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove sudo password when connecting to \*new\* WiFi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244567/remove-sudo-password-when-connecting-to-new-wifi-network)

Comment: This is a 10 year old Grandfather question. It has a score of 6 and two answers. It should remain open. The proposed **duplicated** question is only 7 years old.

Answer (score 2):

If the wireless is working; that is, a driver is installed, then you should be able to click the Network Manager icon, see your network and connect. If the wireless is not working because it needs to have a driver installed, then you cannot proceed without administrator privileges. The administrator password is required to modify the system and install software, including drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I found success with the following solution in Ubuntu 13.04:

Open /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy with root/sudo privileges and search for the following line:

```
<message>System policy prevents modification of network settings for all users</message>
```

A few lines below that should be this:

```
<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
```

Change it to:

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Save the file and restart your computer.

Comment: Oh, yes, that was about it! Running Ubuntu 20.10.