# How can I create a script that allows all users to change network connections?

Tags: networking, scripts

I want to create a bash script to enable all users to connect to wireless networks. Following the instructions on [this page](http://moepad.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/lubuntu-network-access-for-every-user-system-policy/), I can set that and it works. However, I want to be able to do this more quickly by running a script.

I considered using `sed` like this

```
sudo sed -i "s/auth_admin_keep/yes/g" /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy
```

but in this file, there are two instances of `auth_admin_keep` and I only want to replace the first one. I don't want the script to replace the second one even if I accidentally run the script twice.

Comment: Although you can use sed to replace only the first instance, if you run it a second time it would then replace the second. You will need to identify a more specific pattern for your substitution.

Answer (score 1):

> **WARNING:** **This answer is only for 12.04. The file in question could change in future releases, so don't try it in other Ubuntu versions.**

I was able to find the answer to my problem thanks to this site. I need this for Ubuntu 12.04 and the line I need to change is line 695, so this command will get the job done no matter how many times I run it.

```
sudo sed -i "695s/auth_admin_keep/yes/g" /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy
```

Comment: Thanks to which site? Also it is dangerous to change a line blindly without knowing what that is changing. The line can change in future ubuntu releases and even in updates. As in 16.04, that particular line has no such `auth_admin_keep` things

Comment: You're absolutely right. I no longer have a need to do this so I haven't looked for better solutions.

Comment: Could you at least describe the block after change?

Comment: I don't have a system running 12.04 anymore to find that line. Sorry.

Comment: I also changed my approach to solving this problem. http://askubuntu.com/q/244567/109540