# Guest account can't set up wifi connection without admin password

Tags: wireless, 20.04, administrator

I have a guest account which needs the admin password each time they want to connect to a new wifi endpoint. Ideally, this is not the case as I am not always there to enter it. Additionally, it seems like an everyday task to connect to wifi so I don't understand why this needs an admin's permission.

Is there a way to turn off the admin password requirement for wifi connections?

Comment: What is a login manager? I googled it, but I get results for a display manager instead.

Comment: Yes. So the actual laptop with Ubuntu is being used by someone else at a different location. It is true they only have to set up wifi once, but they have to do it without me having access to that laptop. They do use the GUI. I haven't tried `nmcli` as, to be honest, I had no idea it existed. But is that even an option now, as there is no internet connection to the laptop at this moment?

Comment: The default one was `gdm3`, so I installed `lightdm` and then reconfigured `dpkg`.

Comment: Ok, I understand.. Will do it in that way.

Comment: Ok, I confirm the asking for admin password. I think `policykit` may help in this regard. Will check now.

Comment: Do you have autologin enabled? If so, it could be the keyring wich is not unlocked and keeps asking for a password. Also you could check `nm-connection-editor` to make sure the `all users may connect to this network` option is enabled by default.

Comment: Seems this file has the configuration.
`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy`.

Comment: @starkus autologin is not enabled.

Comment: @UnKNOWn thanks! I will have a look at that and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Updating the policy has indeed solved the issue. Thank you very much! Would you mind making this an answer to the question? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it in guest-session in the Question and successfully connected to new wifi connections scanned.

as a super user edit the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy`

find the below part

```
  <action id="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system">
    <description>Modify network connections for all users</description>
...
...
...
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin_keep</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin_keep</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

Edit the line `<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>` to `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>`

save the file and restart the gnome-shell with "Alt+F2 r Enter" Method.

[image]

credits: https://askubuntu.com/a/315900/739431

Comment: Nice workaround!